# Shadow on ray marching volume material

Tags: unreal-engine4, hlsl, raymarching

I'm trying to implement shadows in the beam material from UE4 DMX Plugin, so I can use it with a flashlight and stop worrying about light trails cause by volumetric fog, the problem is that I really don't know how, actually, I don't know anything about HLSL.

So, if any tech artist wizard can help me and explain like I'm five or give me some material to study, it would be awesome.

Lightbeam code:

```
float traversalDepth = FDepth - NDepth ;
uint numSteps = floor(traversalDepth / StepSize) ;
float3 posOffset = normalize(FSlice-NSlice) * StepSize ;

float Adj = AdjOpp.x;
float Opp = AdjOpp.y + ConeRadius;

float3 cumul = 0;

for(uint i=0; i<numSteps; i++){

///Position & depth at rayHit
float3 pos = NSlice + posOffset * i ;
float depth = NDepth + StepSize * i ;

float dist = length(pos);
float falloff = 1.0f-(length(pos)/MaxDistance);

///Domain Transform
pos.z = -pos.z;
pos /= float3(Opp*2,Opp*2,Adj);

float div = ConeRadius / Opp;
div = (pos.z*(1-div))+div;
pos.xy /= div;

//Falloff old
//float falloff = 1.0-saturate(length(pos));

//Center domain
pos.z -= 0.5 ;

///Clip domain edges.
float maskX = (1-abs(pos.x)) > 0.5 ;
float maskY = (1-abs(pos.y)) > 0.5 ;
float maskZ = (1-abs(pos.z)) > 0.5 ;
if( (maskX*maskY*maskZ) - 0.5 < 0 ) continue ;

///Soft clipping with scene depth.
float dClip = saturate((ScDepth-depth)/SoftClipSize);

// UVs from pos
pos.xy = saturate(pos.xy+0.5);
float2 GoboUV = pos.xy;
float2 ColorUV = pos.xy;

// Gobo scale offset
GoboUV.x = GoboUV.x / NumGobos;
GoboUV.x = GoboUV.x + (GoboIndex/NumGobos) ;

// Gobo scrolling
GoboUV.x = GoboUV.x + (Time*GoboScrollingSpeed);

// Sample Gobo
float GoboSample = TXTpGobo.SampleLevel(TXTpGoboSampler,GoboUV.xy,0) ;

// Color Wheel scale offset
ColorUV.x = ColorUV.x / NumColors;
ColorUV.x = ColorUV.x + (ColorIndex/NumColors) ;

// Color scrolling
ColorUV.x = ColorUV.x + ((Time-CurrentTime) * ColorScrollingSpeed);
```

Material:
https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/zf-3xwb_/

[Beam Material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44MDo.png)